# Android : Show layout from the bottom of the screen on button click

Tags: android

Recently i have installed an application from the play store named walnut where i saw a new feature for popup.In the home screen there is a FloatingActionMenu,when clicking on the menu button it will expand with the items on it,on top of that expanded menu there is an option for add account, and on clicking that option a popup will come from the bottom of the screen to a certain height.I likes to know what feature is used for that popup from the bottom of the screen.Is it really a popup or sliding drawer? I want to use exactly the same feature in my android application.If anyone knows about this feature please help me.Below is the screenshot of this popup layout that comes on button click in walnut application.
[image: Popup layout from the bootom of the screen]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the walnut app. I can barely visualize what you are trying to achieve

Comment: yes.I will attach that.Please wait..

Comment: @ribads i have attached the screenshot.Please take a look on that.

Comment: Its better to use **BottomSheet** third party library.

Comment: @KJEjava48 use snackBar with custom design. See answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use dialog with custom layout in it. only thing you have to do is call it from bottom and use style as material dialog sheet like this

```
 final Dialog mBottomSheetDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.MaterialDialogSheet);
                            mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view); // your custom view.
                            mBottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(true);
                            mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
                            mBottomSheetDialog.show();
```

I change my layout height to 800 instead of wrap content and here is the result.

**style.xml**

```
<style name="MaterialDialogSheet" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MaterialDialogSheetAnimation</item>
    </style>



<style name="MaterialDialogSheetAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_show</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_hide</item>
    </style>
```

**anim**

**popup_show.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="300"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

**popup_hide.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="300"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

[image]

Comment: may be because effect is quite same. wait I will send my pop up image.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake . it is old project of mine I forgot :)

Comment: I am updating my answer.

Comment: put in in drawable for temporary. it is fine.

Comment: ohk forgot it create anim folder in resource and add xml in it.

Comment: I think you done some mistake because all thing i provided you are able to display same result as mine

Comment: oh yes thats my mistake..now its fine..but now there is another problem that there is a edittext inside the popup dialog and when clicking on the edittext the keyboard comes and it hides the edittext.Is there any way to show the edittext above the keyboard when keyboard comes

Comment: I set the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" .But still the keyboard hides the edittext on editing.

Comment: Set scrollview as your dialog custom layout parent

Answer (score 3):

You can go with BottomSheetLayout..

https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet

Comment: @Raja Jawahar is there a way to do this without using the third party libraries??

Comment: @KJEjava48.. Android provides this option with support library.  http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a custom view; So trying to use SnackBar would too much hassle. You can however achieve this more easily with BottomSheet(https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet).

Comment: is there a way to do this without using the third party libraries??

Comment: Definitely. You just need a way to inflate the custom view to your activity. Then manage its visibility(probably animated) based on the event that is to reveal the view. Not to mention that you also need to handle state charges in your activity such as BackPress, rotation and other changes that can affect your layout.

Answer (score 1):

Use snackbar for achieve this

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(coordinatorLayout, "Welcome to AndroidHive", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

snackbar.show();
```

XML Design:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSimpleSnackbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Simple Snackbar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnActionCallback"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="With Action Callback" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCustomSnackbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Custom Color" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Got reference from [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/)

Comment: i think snackbar is used to display a message with an action.It contains only one textView and an action as per my knowledge.I think we can't customize this with a xml layout.Look at the layout in the screenshot that i have attached in my question.

Comment: I posted this answer before adding screenshot